# CakePHP- Saving Related Model Data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Ok, lets say there are two associated models, where the main model has a hasMany relationship with the other model. ex Donor hasMany Donations. I have read most of cake's documentation and I also took note of this (from the doc):

> 'When working with associated models, it is important to realize that
>   saving model data should always be done by the corresponding CakePHP
>   model. If you are saving a new Post and its associated Comments, then
>   you would use both Post and Comment models during the save operation'(http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

And as also pointed out by @burzum on another one of my questions : [CakePHP - Controller or No Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468040/cakephp-controller-or-no-controller/21469207?noredirect=1#comment32413696_21469207) , I am still struggling on how to decide which works best.

So taking the 'Donor and Donation' example mentioned earlier, let's say we want the user to add  donation to a donor.  So for the user to add a donation, one would need to view a donor, accessing a url of the sort : 'domain/donors/view/1', meaning the user is currently viewing donor with id of 1. Then within that view, let us assume there is button which allows the user to add a donation. Now from what I have been told and from what I read, the add(donation) action should belong to the donationsController.

Let us also assume that the add(donation) action has its own view.. So if I am at 'domain/donors/view/1' the user is redirected to 'domain/donations/add/donor_id:1' where the id of the donor is then retrieved using 
`$this->request->params['named']['post_id']` 
and  set to the FK like so : 
`$this->request->data['Donation']['donor_id'] = $id;

But I have a gut feeling telling me that this is not the proper way to go and it feels like bad practice jumping from one controller to the other, when having associated models.

Any insight on this ? Is there a general rule of thumb one could apply or follow ? Is it ok to redirect the user from the donorsController's view action to the donationsController's add action ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: excellent! what is defination of donors and donations?

Comment: @Anubhav, what do you mean by definition of donors and donations? The donors represents the CRUD of donor records, where donor info such as name, surname,  donation_count, etc is stored. Donations are associated with the donor, where a blood bank staff member will be able to add donation records for registered donors(donors table). Thanks

Comment: Well there is only one thumb rule keep your code clean and understandable. donors and donations controller must have respective functionality. Do not mix them, rest everything is fine, your will face multiple iterations in next 1 -2 years and you will realize then you will able to understand what is needed at that of time.

Comment: @Anubhav So if im understanding correctly, each controller must have its OWN actions, and as long as the data retrieved 'belongs' to the model of that controller, then it is best to use that controller and its view to represent that data! Cheers mate! you've been of great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know your approach is not wrong, and linking other controllers from a view is normal.

However i prefer (and that's my rule of thumb, i'm not sure is a "best practice") to give the user the change of add an associated model - donations in your case - directly from the view of the "main" model. I've used this kind of approach in my applications, mostly considering the user experience (don't know if it is your case). So, if you are in the edit action of Donor, in the respective view the user can add the Donation and send it to still the edit action of Donor. Here you can save the associated model if the request data are well formatted:

```
data['Donor'] = array('id'=> XX);
data['Donation'] = array('id' => YY, 'amount' => blabla,...);
$this->Donor->save(data);
```

That would respect the MVC (no ugly ClassRegistry::Load ... ) and keep the code simple, avoiding to jump from one controller to another.
Just my opinion :D

Regards.

Comment: Riccardo Barbotti, thanks for this.. This was my initial thought aswell, especially in terms of UX, yes! I value your opinion! Best regards